# Bash sort based on single field and compare based on another field

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates

I have a tab-delimited file with some duplicated rows.  I am interested in finding rows with duplicates in the second field (position) and then keeping only the row with the highest value in the third field (quality).
For example, if a file looks like below:

```
chrom 1677 800
chrom 1677 850
chrom 1777 900
chrom 1799 900
```

I am interested in retaining only a single row for each position that represents the highest quality:

```
chrom 1677 850
chrom 1777 900
chrom 1799 900
```

I can find the duplicated positions with:
awk 'seen[$2]++' file.txt

But I am not sure how to compare duplicated rows from the second field based on the value in the third field.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably [format the data](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydir$ echo $'chrom\t1677\t800\nchrom\t1677\t850\nchrom\t1779\t900\nchrom\t1777\t900' > tmp.txt
mydir$ cat tmp.txt
chrom   1677    800
chrom   1677    850
chrom   1779    900
chrom   1777    900
mydir$ sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 -k3,3nr tmp.txt | awk -v FS='\t' 'val!=$2 {val=$2;print}'
chrom   1677    850
chrom   1777    900
chrom   1779    900
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$e"
chrom 1677 800
chrom 1677 850
chrom 1777 900
chrom 1799 900
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$e" | awk '{if (m[$2]<$3) {m[$2]=$3; seen[$2]=$0}} 
                    END {for (e in seen) print seen[e]}'
chrom 1677 850
chrom 1777 900
chrom 1799 900
```

If your file is tab separated and really a file:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{if (m[$2]<$3) {m[$2]=$3; seen[$2]=$0}} 
              END {for (e in seen) print seen[e]}' file
```